# Grouping data issue

Tags: sql, group-by

I have created dummy table to explore grouping concept in SQL.

I want to group data to show,

1. Total marks of student.
2. Want to display subjects in comma separated way.

My question: why isn't SQL permitting to keep only `StudentID` in the `GROUP BY` clause, it is allowing when we mentioned ID,name,.. other columns in `GROUP BY` clause.

I get this error:

> Column 'SampleData.StudentName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

And how to display subjects in comma separated way in SQL output?

This is the SQL I have written:

```
SELECT
    StudentID, 
    StudentName,
    Standard,
    Subject,
    SUM(MarksObtained) 
FROM
    SampleData
GROUP BY
    StudentID, StudentName 
    --,Standard 
    --,Subject 
ORDER BY 
    StudentID
```

Sample table for reference:

```
StudentID StudentName Standard Subject MarksObtained 
-----------------------------------------------------
1         A           VI       Maths              59   
3         C           VII      English            62   
2         B           IX       Maths              75   
2         B           IX       English            81   
1         A           VI       Science            47   
1         A           VI       History            61
```

Expected output:

```
StudentID StudentName Standard Subject                MarksObtained 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         A           VI       Maths,Science,History  167   
3         C           VII      English                62   
2         B           IX       Maths,English          156
```

Comment: which dbms are you working on ?

Comment: SQL Server.
But, I want general query which will work on all servers.

Comment: for string concat you cannot have general query. check my answer please

Comment: Thanks for Info Simonare.
It is clear now. Will post it again if there is any query related to this.
Any Idea, How to achieve this in SQL Server 2012  ?

Comment: Thanks @GMB fo rthe Info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 1st question:

when you issue aggregation such as sum, count, max,min, avg you need to group other non-aggregated columns. Aggregation is done with respect to grouped columns.

*In english your query means,*

Get sum of MarksObtained from SampleData with respect to   StudentID, StudentName, Standard, Subject

*For the 2nd Question:*

we need to know which DBMS you are working on. Every DBMS system has its own methods for this

- Oracle has `LISTAGG(column, ',')`
- MySQL has `GROUP_CONCAT(column, ',')`
- SQL Server has `STR_AGG(column, ',')`
- PostgreSQL has `string_agg(column, ',')`

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to explictly put in the `GROUP BY` clause all the non-aggregared fields that are `SELECT`ed. Some RDBMS are strict about it (eg Oracle), others may be lax (eg MySQL with sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled).

To concatenate the `Subject` in a single field, you need an aggregate function. Not all RDBMS have the same standard for that. They usually accept an `ORDER BY` option.

Using SQL Server 2017 or higher : `STR_AGG` :

```
SELECT
     StudentID 
    ,StudentName 
    ,Standard 
    ,STR_AGG(Subject, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY StudentID)
    ,SUM(MarksObtained) 
FROM
    SampleData
GROUP BY
     StudentID 
    ,StudentName 
    ,Standard 
ORDER BY 
    StudentID
```

With MySQL : `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
SELECT
     StudentID 
    ,StudentName 
    ,Standard 
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(Subject ORDER BY StudentID SEPARATOR ', ')
    ,SUM(MarksObtained) 
FROM
    SampleData
GROUP BY
     StudentID 
    ,StudentName 
    ,Standard 
ORDER BY 
    StudentID
```

Using Oracle 11g or higher : `LISTAGG` :

```
SELECT
     StudentID 
    ,StudentName 
    ,Standard 
    ,LISTAGG(Subject, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY StudentID)
    ,SUM(MarksObtained) 
FROM
    SampleData
GROUP BY
     StudentID 
    ,StudentName 
    ,Standard 
ORDER BY 
    StudentID
```

Comment: To be fair, MySQL is not lax about the group by rule if the sql mode includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, and this has been enabled by default since MySQL 5.7.5 (2014-09-25).

Comment: So, It is always good practice to include all non-aggregared fields in GROUP BY clause that are SELECT ed irrespective whether DBMS allowed it not.

Comment: @BillKarwin : yes you are correct, MySQL is not so lax since then, I updated my answer to mention it.

Comment: @AnujThite : yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you all.
I will make this as thumb rule while doing SQL development..

Comment: Regarding non-aggregated fields in mentioned GROUP BY clause,
Is the order matters in terms of query perfomance ?
Should it be same as field order mentioned in SELECT Clause ?

Comment: @AnujThite : no, order of the fields in the `SELECT`/ `GROUP BY` clause does not matter, it does not have to be the same.